# How to call a python function with arguments contained in a df?

Tags: python, pandas, function, lambda

my df has integer values that I want to call with a function `Graph`. Also, the function takes as arguments only a certain class `Nodes`. What is the most efficient way to do this? I thought of `iterrows`, but the function is very slow...

The df looks like this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'first':[11,22],
...                   'second':[11,33]})
>>> df
   first  second
0     11      22
1     11      33


11 = Node(11)
22 = Node(22)
33 = Node(33)

g = Graph([11,22,33])

g.connect(11,22)
g.connect(11,33)
```

The function is part of a Dijkstra’s Shortest Path Algorithm, based on https://www.cantorsparadise.com/dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm-in-python-d955744c7064

Comment: You don't show the function you're talking about. That aside, unless you're implementing graph stuff yourself for fun, you should probably just use the `networkx` module.

Comment: I don't understand what you think it means to "load" data "into" a function. You *call* a function with *arguments*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel thanks, I've updated the text accordingly

Comment: @AKX, I thought about this, but my data set contains thousands of nodes and I want to get several shortest paths connecting two nodes. This would taking too much time for networkx to run... Hence I thought of using the Dijkstra algorithm and adding a break command if the shortest path gets longer than two nodes. Or is there a way to tell networkx to stop the computation after two?